# How to print an exception?

Tags: python, exception

How to print python exception?

Example:

```
try:
    action()
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
```

Prints:

`Unexpected error: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>`

It does not have much information for me.

Comment: What more did you want to know?

Comment: What about why exeption was raised? Or where?

Comment: note the simple way too : `except Exception as e`, with  `print e`

Comment: Well what about them? Did you do any research? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232201/how-in-python-find-where-exception-was-raised, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690600/python-exception-message-capturing, ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print an exception in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483429/how-to-print-an-exception-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [traceback module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/traceback.html):

```
try:
    action()
except:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the exception which occurred too.

```
try:
    action()
except exception as ex:
    print("Exception: " + str(ex))
```